# What is the purpose of groups in JupyterHub?

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to limit file access for certain users. Basically, I want team members A to have access to the project A folder, and team members B to have access to the project B folder.
But it seems to me that Jupyter's groups are not made for this. I don't understand what these groups are for, and the documentation doesn't seem clear to me. Could you please help me?

Comment: are you talking about [this type of group admin configuration?](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rbac/use-cases.html?highlight=groups#group-admin-roles) this looks like it's purely related to who has elevated permissions to administer user groups and start/stop/access other users's servers. this doesn't have anything to do with shared storage.

Comment: Ok that's what I was afraid of. So I guess that the only solution would be to manage folder access with chmod/chown. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: what sort of hardware are you running on? are you running jupyterhub with multiple users on a single machine? if so, then yeah this would probably work. if users are running on containerized deployments on kubernetes or something I don't see how you could use chown to grant users access to shared folders.

Comment: Yes users will run it with Kubernetes. I did not know that it would be impossible to use chown but it makes sense. So i do not know how to give access to only some people..

Comment: Yeah I don't know of one either, short of giving users different credentials files or having them log into the cloud provider with their personal logins and then managing access there, neither of which are recommended for security reasons. Jupyterhub isn't really built to manage complex permissions, especially for data access, like this at the moment.

Comment: I see an option for loading 'groups' and 'users' during startup at https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/api/app.html?highlight=group#jupyterhub.app.JupyterHub.load_groups .... But not sure how to access these during the spawner startup ..